# css calc expressions not validated by w3cvalidator and not working in real life either

Tags: css, validation

why does the w3c css validator give me errors on these expressions:

```
#logo {
width: calc(0.85*6.25rem);
height: calc (10.8125rem*0.85);
}

.navpad {
padding-top: calc(0.05*(100% - 12*1.5*1rem - (10.8125rem*0.85)));
}
```

thanks for any tips

Comment: `root ems` don't work for me.. Try with `ems`, also try adding a space between each number and operator. Finally try to have only one calculation per bracket.. So break up `100% - 12*1.5*1rem` with another set of brackets.. Try all and let me know =) calc is only supported on some browsers.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that the `calc()` function is considered an at-risk feature and may be dropped from the spec during the CR period. I wouldn't recommend using it in production code.

Comment: See [Parse errors when using calc with rem and px](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18035088/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

You should to remove whitespace here: `calc (10.8125rem*0.85);`