# Parse errors when using calc with rem and px

Tags: css, w3c-validation, css-calc

I have the following CSS:

```css
body {
  width: calc(700px + 2 * 4rem);
}

.someclass {
  margin: calc(2rem - 2px) 0;
}
```

When I run this through the W3C CSS validation, I get

> Value Error : width Parse Error + 2 * 4rem)
>   Value Error : margin Parse Error - 2px) 0

What’s causing this? All the units I’m using in `calc()` are length units, and `calc()` should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in w3 css validator:

https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=18913

Comment: @Adrift: The validator is extremely buggy. That's all you need to know, really :)

Comment: Thank you. Sanity regained.

Comment: Sanity? If the validator itself is buggy, what hope do we have? :]