# W3C CSS validation error using calc() and vendor extensions

Tags: css, w3c-validation

After finishing my new HTML5/CSS3 template I proceeded to W3C validation.

The result for HTML: "This document was successfully checked as HTML5!"

The result for CSS: "Sorry! We found the following errors (1)"

And the problem is around `height: calc(100vh - 80px);`

It also told me:

```
36      Property -ms-transform is an unknown vendor extension
37      Property -webkit-transform is an unknown vendor extension
112     Property -webkit-transition is an unknown vendor extension
113     Property -moz-transition is an unknown vendor extension
249     Property -webkit-background-size is an unknown vendor extension
292     Property -webkit-background-size is an unknown vendor extension
```

So in this case what shall I do to get it 100% CSS3 valid?

Comment: it doesn't matter. ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about the vendor extensions. I don't recall why they are flagged that way but they are not errors on your part. I don't recall the reasoning for it. iirc, there is a checkbox to ignore these warnings.

The explanation may lie in [this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200911/vendor-specific_extensions_are_invalid_css/) where it states:

> Vendor-specific extensions (mostly) do adhere to the CSS 2.1 grammar,
>   but since they are not defined in the CSS 2.1 specification, they are
>   invalid. Hence the CSS validator is correct in reporting them as
>   validation errors.

Comment: Indeed there is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889724/how-to-validate-vendor-prefixes-in-css-like-webkit-and-moz

Answer (score 1):

Check out caniuse.com before worrying too much about vendor prefixes:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

In this case, it may be because you don't need them. Based on the w3 specs, too.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

Comment: Vendor prefixes are non-standard, so the spec has no reason to mention them.

Answer (score 1):

#### Regarding `calc()`:

The fact that the [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) reports errors when using `calc()` [is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18035284/1591669):

→ [Support calc() from CSS3 Values](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=18913) (currently still unfixed)

#### Regarding vendor extensions:

Their use is only listed as *warning*, not as *error*.

So your CSS can be valid despite using vendor extensions.