# Why is calc not working with rem and px combined?

Tags: css

I tried the following style on a div but it is saying invalid css:

```
max-width: calc(24rem-13px);
```

The calc is using rem and px combined. If I remove the px part, then browser accepts the calc as valid style.

I am using latest Chrome.

Comment: spacing is important in ```calc()``` css function, ```calc(24rem - 13px);```

Comment: This is a known issue from w3 css validator:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035088/parse-errors-when-using-calc-with-rem-and-px

Comment: Ultimately, this question is a duplicate of [Why doesn't the CSS calc() function work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108285/why-doesnt-the-css-calc-function-work-for-me) in that the cause is the missing whitespace surrounding the operator inside of `calc()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add a space around the minus operator:

```css
.test {
  background-color: gold;
  max-width: calc(24rem - 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">I have a max width</div>
```

It's not working because without the space it could be interpreted as a negative value `calc(24rem - -13px)` for example

Comment: Thanks, Really silly of me to leave out the space.